# I need help creating a map with a moving marker (according to lat and long positions)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using API for fetching latitude and longitude positions live. I wanted to show a map with a smoothly moving marker and an info window. I used ajax to get the data and I also used setinterval. but the issue with that is that after 5 seconds it blinks the map, then it changes its position. I want to show a map with a smoothly moving marker with a track. I even did much research on it - but I can't get an accurate result. I have even used Angularjs - but it was not successful.

If there is anyone that can help me out on this issue, I would be very thankful.

Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function addMarker1()
{

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('welcome/ajax_map');?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            $(response).each(function(key,value)
                    {
                if(key==0)
                {
                    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
                    var res = value.split(",");
                    /* alert(res[0]);
                                        alert(res[1]); */
                    var mapOptions = {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(res[0],res[1]), 
                            zoom: 16,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: value,
                        icon: 'http://58.254.202.73/808gps/ttxmap/google/image/1/online/1.png',
                        map: map
                    }); 

                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(res[0],res[1]);
                    marker.setPosition(latlng);

                    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                            '<div><strong><span id="1"></span></strong></div>'+
                            '<div><strong>position: </strong><span id="0"></span></div>'+
                            '<div><strong>Time: </strong><span id="2"></span></div>'+
                            '<div><strong>Mileage: </strong><span id="3"></span></div>'+
                            '<div><strong>Speed: </strong><span id="4"></span></div>'+
                            '</div>';

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({              //information window
                        content: contentString
                    });

                    infowindow.open(map,marker); 
                    addMarker1();   
                }
                    }); 

        }
    }); 


},500);
addMarker1();
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific code issue, not writing new code from scratch. Please show your working code.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: now here is the code, please let me know your suggestions

Comment: Obviously you will have to separate the fixed stuff from the changing stuff.  Don't put everything in a setInterval !

Comment: Yes i know but setinterval works here only, so i used here

Comment: The only thing you need inside setTimeInterval is marker.setPosition() and map.setCenter().  Don'ts put all the initialize stuff inside, that only has to happen once.